# Por que não precisa instanciar a lista para não acumular?

Tags: java, lista, instanciar-objeto

Eu tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class TesteLista {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> dados;

    Teste1 t = new Teste1();
    dados = t.getList();

    System.out.println(dados);
 }
}
```

Classe que tem o método:

```
public class Teste1 {

public List<String> getList(){
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add("Aline");
    lista.add("João");
    lista.add("Jona");
    lista.add("Pedro");

        return lista;
 }
}
```

Ele imprime:

> [Aline, João, Jona, Pedro]

Por que a lista dados não acumula já que eu não dou `new`? Por que eu não preciso dar `dados= new ArrayList<>();` para não acumular?

Comment: Por que tem um `main()` dentro de `Teste1`? Defina "acumular". Não não dá `new`?

Comment: é como se fosse o Start do meu código.

Comment: Não me parece fazer sentido. Qual dos dois é o `main()` de fato? Alias, qual é a dúvida?

Comment: A minha dúvida é por que eu não preciso dar new na lista dados? E porque ela não acumula???

Comment: acumular é tipo fazer isso com a lista dados:  [Aline, João, Jona, Pedro Aline, João, Jona, Pedro, Aline, João, Jona, Pedro] a cada execução entrar mais na lista

Comment: Isto você já escreveu, agora explique o que isso quer dizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que você está fazendo é uma  cópia de referencias de um tipo `List` entre variáveis. Por isso não precisa instanciar, pois você já está atribuindo um elemento que já foi instanciado e copiando sua referência para a variável `dados`.

Imagine que seu código fosse assim:

```
List<String> dados;

...

List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("Aline");
lista.add("João");
lista.add("Jona");
lista.add("Pedro");

...

dados = lista;
```

É mais ou menos isso que está ocorrendo. A variável `dados` é `nula` ao ser iniciada, mas ao atribuir a ela a referencia da lista criada dentro da sua classe `Teste01`, ela passa a "apontar" para aquela lista.

Comment: Awwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww entendi :O

Answer (score 4):

Acho que sua interpretação do que é o código está errada. Provavelmente não está pensando como ele é executado, imagino que ache que coloca palavras e magicamente algo acontece. Tudo que é escrito tem uma consequência e é preciso entender todo o processo, caso contrário não aprenderá programar.

Vamos entender o que ocorre com a lista:

Na linha

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

é criada uma lista de *strings* e é referenciada por uma variável chamada `lista`.

Nas linhas seguintes

```
lista.add("Aline");
lista.add("João");
lista.add("Jona");
lista.add("Pedro");
```

são adicionados elementos para este lista.

Finalmente na linha

```
return lista;
```

a lista é retornada para quem chamou. A variável `lista` deixa de existir, mas o objeto apontado por ela, no caso a lista com 4 elementos ainda existe e passará ser apontada por quem chamou este método.

Agora voltamos ao método principal. Na linha

```
Teste1 t = new Teste1();
```

é criado um objeto do tipo `Teste1` e colocado na variável `t´. Na verdade não precisaria existir um objeto só para isto, mas vamos lá.

Na linha

```
dados = t.getList();
```

o método é chamado e o seu retorno, aquela nossa lista é passada para a variável dados que já havia sido declarada. Então agora `dados` passa ter a lista que estava na variável `lista` dentro do método `getList()`.

Finalmente a linha

```
System.out.println(dados);
```

imprime a lista.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/ListExplain.java).

Não precisa de outro `new` em qualquer lugar porque só precisa criar a lista uma vez. Não tem nada que "acumular" porque o código não manda fazer isto. Se ele mandasse fazer então faria. Seria até impossível ter `[Aline, João, Jona, Pedro Aline, João, Jona, Pedro, Aline, João, Jona, Pedro]` porque só uma lista com apenas 4 elementos foi criado.

É preciso entender o que o código está fazendo senão fica repetindo códigos prontos e não sabe o que está fazendo.

Eu até imagino que deseja fazer outras coisa, mas a pergunta sequer fala nisto. Antes de programar é preciso entender o problema e expressá-lo em português mesmo. Se isto não puder ser feito, é certo que em Java não ficará certo, já que a base está errada.

Comment: Hummmmmm. Achei sua resposta arrogante. Não entendi, foi eu que criei todo esse codegozinho e você vem me dizer que copiei de outro lugar?

Comment: Mas entendi aqui eu só mando criar quatro itens...obrigada de qualquer forma...

Comment: Eu disse que não está entendendo o que está fazendo. Você está no site há bastante tempo e ainda não entendeu como os códigos funcionam. Eu entendo que ouvir que não nos agrada soa como arrogante. Algumas pessoas tomam assim e não evoluem, outras aceitam a dica e começam dar um passo à frente. Evolução é uma questão de atitude de reconhecer onde está falhando e começar mudar. Cada um aproveita as dicas como quiser.